# x86 Intrinsic : FIR for complex float input

Tags: c, sse, convolution, complex-numbers, avx

My input is 2 float vectors. One is the real part of complex input. The second is the imaginary part of the same complex input.

I developed the following code for calculating FIR on a float input.
In case of FIR, I suspect the input should be complex float (Re,Im, Re, Im,...) and not float (Re, Re, ...)

```
    void CVector::Fir(float* pInRe, float *pInIm, float* pOutRe, 
float *pOutIm, float* pCoeff, uint32_t N, uint32_t FilterLength)
{
    int n, k;
    float* pSrcRe;
    float* pSrcIm;
    float* pCoeffSrc = pCoeff;
    float* pDstRe = pOutRe;
    float* pDstIm = pOutIm;
    __m128 Zero128 = _mm_set_ps1(0);

    __m256 VecRe, VecIm;
    __m256 SumRe, SumIm;
    uint32_t Offset;
    __m128 Low, High, Sum128;

    for (n = 0; n < N; n++)
    {
        pSrcRe = pInRe;
        pSrcIm = pInIm;
        SumRe = _mm256_set1_ps(0);
        SumIm = SumRe;
        Offset = FilterLength - 1 - n;
        pCoeffSrc = pCoeff + Offset;

        for (k = Offset; k < FilterLength; k += 8)
        {
            __m256 Coeff = _mm256_load_ps(pCoeffSrc);
            VecRe = _mm256_load_ps(pSrcRe);
            VecIm = _mm256_load_ps(pSrcIm);
            SumRe = _mm256_fmadd_ps(Coeff, VecRe, SumRe);
            SumIm = _mm256_fmadd_ps(Coeff, VecIm, SumIm);
            pCoeffSrc += 8;
            pSrcRe += 8;
            pSrcIm += 8;
        }

        //Accumlate 8 elements in Sum128
        //extract 4 low float from Sum
        Low = _mm256_castps256_ps128(SumRe);
        //extract 4 high float from Sum
        High = _mm256_extractf32x4_ps(SumRe, 1);
        //Add Low, High into __mm128
        Sum128 = _mm_add_ps(Low, High);
        //Pack to __mm128 with one element > 0 
        Sum128 = _mm_hadd_ps(Sum128, Zero128);
        Sum128 = _mm_hadd_ps(Sum128, Zero128);
        //extract float[0] from Sum128
        *pDstRe = _mm_cvtss_f32(Sum128);


        //Accumlate 8 elements in Sum128
        //extract 4 low float from Sum
        Low = _mm256_castps256_ps128(SumIm);
        //extract 4 high float from Sum
        High = _mm256_extractf32x4_ps(SumIm, 1);
        //Add Low, High into __mm128
        Sum128 = _mm_add_ps(Low, High);
        //Pack to __mm128 with one element > 0 
        Sum128 = _mm_hadd_ps(Sum128, Zero128);
        Sum128 = _mm_hadd_ps(Sum128, Zero128);
        *pDstIm = _mm_cvtss_f32(Sum128);

        pDstRe++;
        pDstIm++;
    }
}
```

Can you please advise if the input (and output) should be interleaved or separate real, imag ?

Comment: It's adding adjacent elements of the dot-product accumulator down to one scalar, which doesn't make sense for interleaved real and imaginary parts.  IDK how this exact code could work for separate Re and Im arrays either, though, since `_mm256_fmadd_ps` doesn't do a complex multiply.  But if you mean replacing that with a complex multiply and accumulate, yes, that would be *much* better than interleaved Re,Im; that's a disaster for SIMD vs. doing pure vertical to get 8 complex products with a few vector ops and no shuffles.

Comment: Hi Peter - Thank you very much for your reply. I modified the inner (k) loop. Can you please tell if this the right way ?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Multiplication_and_square and [Using FMA (fused multiply) instructions for complex multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30089859) for how to multiply complex numbers!

Comment: If the `pCoeff` coefficients are real numbers, you only have `real*complex` products. You still save some shuffling, by having the complex numbers de-interleaved. But ultimately it is a design-choice (likely depending on whether you need to interact with other libraries) how you store your complex numbers.

Comment: You are computing a convolution, which can be done much more efficient if you don't compute every output value separately. How large is your `FilterLength`? Is it always a multiple of 8?

Comment: (N.B.: `void CVector::Fir(...)` is not valid in C. And even in C code there is no need to declare every variable at the beginning of the function, unless you compile with a very old standard).

Comment: Hi chtz . Thank you for your reply. In my case the filter length is 60. How can it help if it's 64 ?

Comment: Peter - In my case the input is complex float. The filter is float.  I'm using _mm256_fmadd_ps. Can you please clarify what fuse operation should I use ?

Comment: If you want people to see your replies, make sure to notify them like @ZviVered .  (You get notified when people comment under your post, but we don't get notified when you post comments that don't tag anyone.  SO has some heuristics for that case, but I didn't see this until looking at your followup question).  Anyway, I linked the math and a question about doing it with FMA.  It takes multiple instructions.

Comment: @ZviVered It can help to extend the filter coefficients with zeros to 64 (maybe even to 128, if you do some FFT based convolution). I suggest to start with some working scalar code and unit tests, though. E.g. `Offset = FilterLength - 1 - n;` will wrap-around to maxint32 when `n==FilterLength`, which likely is not intended.